# Torch/lua, how to join together two arrays?

Tags: arrays, lua, torch

I have the following array in Torch/lua:

```
aaa = {1, 2, 3, 4}

bbb = {0, 0, 0, 1}
```

I would like to use a function that **merges them into the following a unique array**, by keeping the order first by position and then by array (a1, b1, a2, b2, a3, b3, ...).

For example, the output of the merge of `aaa` and `bbb` should be:

```
merged = {1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 1}
```

How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

my example for indexed tables (arrays):

```
local aaa = {1, 2, 3, 4}
local bbb = {0, 0, 0, 1}
local max= (#aaa>#bbb) and #aaa or #bbb
local merged = {}
for i=1,max do
   if aaa[i] then merged[#merged+1] = aaa[i] end
   if bbb[i] then merged[#merged+1] = bbb[i] end
end

for k,v in pairs(merged) do
 print(k,v)
end
```